ReplaceRepeated ( //. ) does not work as expected
I have a list expr of symbols.
Clear["Global`*"];

$Version
(* 14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024) *)

expr = {a,d,c,b,f,c,a,X,X,a,b,b,X,b,f,c,b,d,a,f,X,d,d,c,X,X,f,f,c,f};

I want to move all X's to the right. This goal can be achieved by
wanted = Join[DeleteCases[expr, X], Cases[expr, X]]

(* {a,d,c,b,f,c,a,a,b,b,b,f,c,b,d,a,f,d,d,c,f,f,c,f,X,X,X,X,X,X} *)

But I want a rule-based solution using ReplaceRepeated[] because this is suitable for my ultimate goal. I tried
rule = {{p___, X, q_, r___} :> {p, q, X, r}};
expr2 = expr //. rule

(* {a,d,c,b,f,c,a,X,X,a,b,b,X,b,f,c,b,d,a,f,X,d,d,c,X,X,f,f,c,f} *) 

My question is: Why ReplaceRepeated[] stopped there? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm on the road, but my first guess is that when q matches X, the replacement results in the same expression. Would that cause it to stop?

@MichaelE2 I see now. Got it thanks! Should I post a solution myself?

Any reason why not rule={p___,X,r___}:>{p,r,X}; expr2=expr//.rule  which in V 14.1 on windows gives https://i.sstatic.net/GsWl8AYQ.png  {a,d,c,b,f,c,a,a,b,b,b,f,c,b,d,a,f,d,d,c,f,f,c,f,X,X,X,X,X,X}

@Nasser Because I want to implement a commutation relation of Lie algebra --- I need to move one by one.

@MichaelE2 I found a workaround, but cannot find no satisfactory answer to my question itself...

Does this help with finding an explanation: {a, X, c, d, X, b, X} //. {{p___, X, q_, r___} :> (Print[{"q" -> q, #}]; #) &@{p, q, X, r}}? It prints the replacement for each match. lericr has already explained the point in my comment.

If you make your rule {{p___, X, q : Except[X], r___} :> {p, q, X, r}} or {{p___, X, r__} :> {p, r, X}}, it will work.

@MichaelE2 Thank you very much. Yes, I can confirm that as soon as q matches X, the rule produces no change and the loop is quitted.

@SjoerdSmit Thank you. It really works as I expected. I also found that {{p___, Longest[x : X ..], q_, r___} :> {p, q, x, r}} do the same job.

ReplaceRepeated stops evaluating when the expression no longer changes. When it encounters two X adjacent to each other, the rule moves the first X to just after the subsequent X, but at that point, the expression is indistinguishable from what it was previously. So, ReplaceRepeated stops.

ReplaceList[expr2, rule] returns several different results. Does ReplaceRepeated give up applying rules after just one invariant case although there are non-invariant cases?

@A.Kato Yes, I pretty sure it stops at the first match. ReplaceRepeated doesn't care if the replacement results in no effective change.

Thank you for clear explanation. FullSimplify[] tries wider range of transformation than Simplify[]. In the same way, I had assumed ReplaceRepeated[] tries all possible matching pattern which is avalable by ReplaceList[]. I learned from your answer and from others's comments that ReplaceRepeated[] try to round things up as quickly as possible instead of aiming for perfection :-) Probably this is a tip to avoid the danger of getting stuck in an infinite loop.

@A.Kato For fun, one way to do what you imagined ReplaceRepeated worked: {a, d, c, b, f, c, a, X, X, a, b, b, X, b, f, c, b, d, a, f, X, d, d, c, X, X, f, f, c, f} //. whole_ :> Last@DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[ReplaceList[whole, {{p___, X, q_, r___} :> ({p, q, X, r})}], whole]]

@MichaelE2 Thank you so much. This is indeed "Full" or "Try Hard" version of "ReplaceRepeated".
